# Mongoose: Remove Document and all references completely

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was wondering. I have a lot of coding to do with a function to remove a document from the database. Basically removing just the object is not that much work, but removing the _id reference from all the other models step by step in the right order is the big work load (I pushed the object ID into the other objects so I could create relations and populate later).

I was wondering: is there no function standard in mongoose that instantly removes the document as well as all its objectId references in the documents of the other model types (so completely remove the object and all it's ObjectID references in all the other collections in the DB)?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are looking for using this NPM package called
**cascading-relations** [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cascading-relations)